# Why is root view set to zero size after dismissing a modal VC, when Auto Layout constraints are installed on UIWindow?

Tags: ios, objective-c, autolayout

I try to use Auto Layout for my application's root view, i.e. I install Auto Layout constraints in the application's `UIWindow` and enable Auto Layout on the root VC's view.

The problem: When I dismiss a modally presented VC, the view hierarchy "collapses" and only the `UIWindow` remains visible. I assume that the root VC's view is resized to zero.

If I do not use Auto Layout on the application's root view everything seems to work fine.

My question: Is it forbidden to use Auto Layout for an application's root view? If not, what am I doing wrong? If yes, is this restriction documented somewhere in the official Apple docs, or is it merely "common knowledge"?

The following code is a minimal sample application that demonstrates the problem. You can simply copy&paste the code into a new Xcode project (use the "empty application" template).

```
#pragma mark Interface declarations

@interface AppDelegate : UIResponder <UIApplicationDelegate>
@property (strong, nonatomic) UIWindow* window;
@end

@interface PresentingViewController : UIViewController
@end

@interface PresentedViewController : UIViewController
@end

#pragma mark AppDelegate implementation

@implementation AppDelegate

- (BOOL) application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
  // Set this to false and the problem goes away
  bool useAutoLayout = true;

  self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
  self.window.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

  PresentingViewController* pvc = [[PresentingViewController alloc] init];

  UINavigationController* nc = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:pvc];
  self.window.rootViewController = nc;
  [self.window addSubview:nc.view];

  if (useAutoLayout)
  {
    nc.view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
    NSDictionary* viewsDict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                               nc.view, @"ncView",
                               nil];
    NSArray* hConstraintsWindow = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|-0-[ncView]-0-|"
                                                                          options:0
                                                                          metrics:nil
                                                                            views:viewsDict];
    [self.window addConstraints:hConstraintsWindow];
    NSArray* vConstraintsWindow = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|-0-[ncView]-0-|"
                                                                          options:0
                                                                          metrics:nil
                                                                            views:viewsDict];
    [self.window addConstraints:vConstraintsWindow];
  }

  nc.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];

  [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
  return YES;
}
@end

#pragma mark PresentingViewController implementation

@implementation PresentingViewController

- (void) loadView
{
  self.view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
  self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];
  self.title = @"presenting vc";
  self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemAdd target:self action:@selector(add:)];
}

- (void) add:(id)sender
{
  PresentedViewController* pvc = [[PresentedViewController alloc] init];
  UINavigationController* navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc]
                                                  initWithRootViewController:pvc];
  navigationController.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCoverVertical;
  [self presentViewController:navigationController animated:YES completion:nil];
}
@end

#pragma mark PresentedViewController implementation

@implementation PresentedViewController

- (void) loadView
{
  self.view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
  self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor yellowColor];
  self.title = @"modal vc";
  self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemDone target:self action:@selector(done:)];
}

- (void) done:(id)sender
{
  [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}

@end
```

---

EDIT: In response to trojanfoe's answer, here are my thoughts why I believe I should be allowed to use Auto Layout for the root view:

1. `UIWindow` is derived from `UIView`, so I see no reason why I should not be allowed to install constraints in it.
2. It's true that there is no `UIViewController` instance that manages a `UIWindow` - but if we talk about the *roles* of the MVC design pattern, from my point of view the application delegate clearly takes the controller role, and therefore should be allowed to set up constraints.

To make this clear: If it's not possible to use Auto Layout on the root view for some technical reason, I will, of course, accept that. In fact, I *want* to be convinced not to use Auto Layout, but I prefer rational argument to blind coding.

Comment: The root view controller's view is supposed to take up the whole of the window, and that is done for you when you add a controller as the root view controller of a window (BTW, you shouldn't also add the view as a subview of the window), so why would you want to add constraints to the window? What is your goal in doing that?

Comment: @rdelmar I am embracing Auto Layout full-scale, so to speak. I admit that I may be a bit overzealous, but on the other hand I don't want to take only half-measures, so wherever I am implementing a controller I want to use Auto Layout - unless that is not possible for some technical reason.

Comment: @rdelmar Why should I not add the root VC's view as a subview to the `UIWindow`? I can't remember having read this before (which doesn't mean a lot :-)). I noticed that if I don't add the superview/subview relationship explicitly, `UIWindow` will add it for me implicitly. This is very interesting, because one could argue that `UIWindow`, by taking an active role in constructing a view relationship, acts as its own controller. Since I must not mess with a controller's internal layout handling, this would be a good reason not to use Auto Layout for the root view. Is that, perhaps, your argument?

Comment: @rdelmar If this *is* your argument, then you can add it as an answer and I will accept it.

Comment: I don't know that I would argue that the window is acting as a controller, since a controller's main job is to mediate between the model and the view, and a window doesn't know anything about the model. As for adding the root vc's view as a subview of the window, I don't know if it does any harm, but the docs for rootViewController state, that "assigning a view controller to this property (either programmatically or using Interface Builder) installs the view controller’s view as the content view of the window".

Answer (score 1):

I believe you are over-complicating the set-up of the views:

1. Constraints should be set on views only, not on the window.
2. The view controller is responsible for managing the view hierarchy and you don't need to be involved at all.

I think removing your constraints/view manipulation code will solve your issues:

```
PresentingViewController* pvc = [[PresentingViewController alloc] init];
UINavigationController* nc = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:pvc];
self.window.rootViewController = nc;
nc.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
```

Also shouldn't that be `PresentedViewController` given the navigation view controller will do the *presenting*?

Comment: I added my response as an edit to the bottom of the question. As for your naming question: In the implementation of `PresentingViewController` I am saying `[self presentViewController:...`, so the naming seems correct to me. But please, let's not argue this, it's not the point of the question.